# Google colab gpu takes too long to execute code

Tags: python, gpu, google-colaboratory

I am doing my computations in Google Colab. I changed the runtime type to GPU. However I don't see a perceptible change in the time it takes to execute the code when using the GPU.

My question is, do we have to write the code in a particular way in order to leverage the parallelization power of the GPU?

I'm not doing anything fancy. I'm not fetching any data from the drive or any other place which apparently takes up a lot of time.

Comment: Are you using any libraries that can actually use the GPU, like TensorFlow or whatever?

Comment: Yes, I am using TensorFlow. Although, I've timed the executions of the various parts of my code and the parts that are taking significantly longer than the rest, have nothing to do with TensorFlow

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running your code with a profile in order to measure which parts are consuming runtime?

The `%prun` cell magic makes this pretty easy. Here's an example:
[image]

Reproducing the code here:

```
def sum_of_lists(N):
    total = 0
    for i in range(5):
        L = [j ^ (j >> i) for j in range(N)]
        total += sum(L)
    return total
```

Then, to collect an example runtime profile,

```
%prun sum_of_lists(1000000)
```

Comment: I logged time.time() at various points in my code and measured the difference between consecutive time.time() records. The parts taking up the longest time, are nested for-loops.

Comment: @DarthCavader if that's the bottleneck and not your GPU, sounds like you need to optimize or replace your `for` loops.